# How to generate unique sequential id in node or mongoose like A-001, A-002

Tags: node.js, mongoose

How to generate unique id like `A-001`,`A-002` using `nodejs` and `mongoose`?

I have seen `mongoose-auto-increment`, but I need to generate the id based on role.

For example if the role is client their id should be `C-001`, if the role is User their it should be `U-001`.

Sequential ids is in node package having this feature but its having less downloads so is there any other way to generate

Can anyone give me some ideas?

Comment: You can have custome method for this, first get tha last inserted id say A-001 split by - and increment by 1 then merge it will be A-002 then save it

Comment: Thanks for your response, Before get the last inserted id A-001 I need to generate the pattern how to do that

Comment: if role is fixed , then you can have normal if else or switch condition..
if(role == 'client') id = 'C-'+incrementedId ;